# Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP not synched between listeners and the client that actually adds data

Tags: javascript, timestamp, firebase

Here is the simplest example possible:

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/test');

fb.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snap) {
    console.log('key', snap.key());
    console.log('val', snap.val());
});

fb.push({
    date_now: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

If I open two tabs with this script, the one that actually pushes data gets **local** timestamp in child_added callback and the other tab that just listens gets proper server-generated one. As far as I understand it's done to exclude round-trip and save bandwidth.

But for my task this behaviour is unacceptable. How can I overcome it?

This is the console.log from pusher:

```
key -K59mrvEUhTaoNIQQoA4
val Object {date_now: 1449732570832}
```

and listeners (equals to server data seen in dashboard):

```
key -K59mrvEUhTaoNIQQoA4
val Object {date_now: 1449732571759}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase fires two local events for that write operation:

1. it immediately fires a `child_added` event with the local timestamp (corrected for your expected offset to the server)
2. it later fires a `child_changed` event with the actual timestamp as the server specified it.

So you can solve the problem by listening for both events:

```
var fb = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/test');

var query = fb.limitToLast(1);
query.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    console.log('key', snap.key());
    console.log('val', snap.val());
});
query.on('child_changed', function(snap) {
    console.log('key', snap.key());
    console.log('val', snap.val());
});

fb.push({
    date_now: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

In general it is recommended to handle all `child_*` events and not just `child_added`. There may be more reasons why the server has to update or remove the value, to correct for the local event.

If you prefer having a single callback/event handler, you can also listen for the `value` event:

```
var query = fb.limitToLast(1);
query.on('value', function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log('key', child.key());
        console.log('val', child.val());
    });
});
```

You'll note the use of `forEach()` in the callback.

Comment: Listening for "child_changed" solves the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Frank!
In this case, can I be sure that the value returned by child_added will always be different from the value returned by child_changed ?

Comment: No. If there is no clock skew, the value from the server will be the same. It's not likely, but can happen.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen in the case its the same is child_changed still fired?

Comment: If the value is the same, the child hasn't changed, so the `child_changed` event will not fire.

Answer (score 2):

For the Realtime SDK this is the expected behavior. Eventually, the timestamp will reflect the proper server value. But, if this does not suit your needs you can use the REST API.

```
function addTimestamp() {
  fetch('https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/test/.json', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      '.sv': 'timestamp' // add a timestamp
    })
  });
}
```

This will not use the local timestamp, and in combination with the Realtime SDK, each client will have the same timestamp on the first update.