# Why Firebase timestamp changes after setting it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to set an object with a timestamp in Firebase and then read it.

I create a child_added listener on the reference and after that I set my object in the same reference, I suppose that my child_added will return the correct object.

The problem is that my child_added returns an object with a timestamp (i.e 100) that is different from the value on Firebase (i.e 105).

I've seen that after setting my object its timestamp changes (it fires a child_changed event)

I've created a plunkr, you can see the two different timestamps in the console

```
var FW = new Firebase('https://prova-devid.firebaseio.com/');

FW.on('child_added', function(res) {
    console.log('ON_ADD', res.key(), res.val().timestamp);
});

FW.child('test').set({
    timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}, function() {
    FW.child('test').once('value', function(res) {
        console.log('FETCHING IT AGAIN', res.key(), res.val().timestamp);
    });
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jdWR2RPu3OBUFSLkYRF0?p=preview

Why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is expected behavior, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196263/firebase-servervalue-timestamp-not-synched-between-listeners-and-the-client-that/34205892#34205892