# Need Help: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP #firebase

Tags: javascript, server, timestamp, firebase, client

on my local Client Device i have a wrong time. When i update the Database with Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP it uses my wrong client time. I thought Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP uses the server side firebase time. Is that right?

My Query:

```
  ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('profile').update(
    {
      userid: authData.uid,
      username: authData.auth.username,
      lastlogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    },
    function(error){
     if(error===null){
       //…
     }
     else
     {
       //…
     }
    }
  );
```

Thanks für your help!!!

Steffen

Comment: It seems like you have the correct understanding. Can you show us what you expect and what you are getting as a result? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html

Comment: For a description of how `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` works with a local, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196263/firebase-servervalue-timestamp-not-synched-between-listeners-and-the-client-that/34205892#34205892. I expect that you're using a single-value listener?

Comment: If that's not the problem, what is happening? What value is stored? What's the local time?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/96xbBYEvx5Y

Comment: I try to explain it with an little example: The time at the moment is 20:30. I change my local time on my computer to 20:00. Then I update the data with the query above. The data on the database will be updated, but the written timestamp is 20:00 and not 20:30. I thought Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP will automatically insert a serverside timestamp into the database and not my local client time. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found my bug.

I thought .info/serverTimeOffset is the current latency and i calculated the difference wrong. Everything works correct. Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP sets a Server Timestamp as expected. The .info/serverTimeOffset ist the difference to the local client time and not the latency. I don´t remember where i read this wrong info.

Thanks for your help!